# Network analysis: density of communities/partitions (and other metrics)

Tags: r, python, networks, social-network, igraph

After running a community detection algorhythm (e.g. edge betweenness, or greedy modularity), I like know the density of each seperate community, and potentially some other metrics, too.

My desired output would look something like this:

| Community | density | potential other metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.20 | ... |
| 1 | 0.35 | ... |

I reckoned this would be a standard option when using "community" in [Python's NetworkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/community.html) or "community detection" in [R's igraph](https://igraph.org/r/doc/communities.html).

However, I searched for this, and it doesn't seem to exist. Is this right? Am I overlooking something? I plan to programme something myself in Python now, but I'm just really surprised that this isn't already out there. Any tip would be much appreciated! If you have the code already, and you like to share it, that would be great. Otherwise I'm happy to share my solution, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a Python script which gives me exactly what I needed, so I just share it here in case others may need it, too.

The dolphin dataset is used for illustrative purposes, which is converted to two lists, so the example is easy to reproduce (for more info on the data, [see](http://networkrepository.com/soc-dolphins.php))

```
import pandas as pd 
source = ['Beak', 'Beak', 'Beak', 'Beak', 'Beak', 'Beak', 'Beescratch', 'Beescratch', 'Beescratch', 'Beescratch', 'Beescratch', 'Beescratch', 'Beescratch', 'Beescratch', 'Bumper', 'Bumper', 'Bumper', 'Bumper', 'CCL', 'CCL', 'CCL', 'Cross', 'DN16', 'DN16', 'DN16', 'DN16', 'DN21', 'DN21', 'DN21', 'DN21', 'DN21', 'DN21', 'DN63', 'DN63', 'DN63', 'DN63', 'DN63', 'Double', 'Double', 'Double', 'Double', 'Double', 'Feather', 'Feather', 'Feather', 'Feather', 'Feather', 'Fish', 'Fish', 'Fish', 'Five', 'Fork', 'Gallatin', 'Gallatin', 'Gallatin', 'Gallatin', 'Gallatin', 'Grin', 'Grin', 'Grin', 'Grin', 'Grin', 'Grin', 'Grin', 'Grin', 'Grin', 'Grin', 'Haecksel', 'Haecksel', 'Haecksel', 'Haecksel', 'Haecksel', 'Haecksel', 'Hook', 'Hook', 'Hook', 'Hook', 'Hook', 'Jet', 'Jet', 'Jet', 'Jet', 'Jet', 'Jonah', 'Jonah', 'Jonah', 'Jonah', 'Jonah', 'Jonah', 'Knit', 'Knit', 'Kringel', 'Kringel', 'Kringel', 'Kringel', 'Kringel', 'Kringel', 'MN105', 'MN105', 'MN105', 'MN105', 'MN105', 'MN60', 'MN60', 'MN60', 'MN83', 'MN83', 'MN83', 'Mus', 'Mus', 'Notch', 'Oscar', 'Oscar', 'Patchback', 'Patchback', 'Patchback', 'Patchback', 'Patchback', 'PL', 'PL', 'Ripplefluke', 'Scabs', 'Scabs', 'Scabs', 'Scabs', 'Scabs', 'Scabs', 'Shmuddel', 'Shmuddel', 'Shmuddel', 'SN100', 'SN100', 'SN100', 'SN100', 'SN4', 'SN4', 'SN4', 'SN4', 'SN63', 'SN63', 'SN63', 'SN63', 'SN89', 'SN9', 'SN90', 'SN90', 'SN96', 'SN96', 'Stripes', 'Stripes', 'Topless', 'Topless', 'Topless', 'TR120', 'TR82', 'TR99', 'Trigger', 'TSN83', 'Upbang']
target = ['Fish', 'Grin', 'Haecksel', 'SN9', 'SN96', 'TR77', 'Jet', 'Knit', 'Notch', 'Number1', 'Oscar', 'SN100', 'SN90', 'Upbang', 'Fish', 'SN96', 'Thumper', 'Zipfel', 'Double', 'Grin', 'Zap', 'Trigger', 'Feather', 'Gallatin', 'Wave', 'Web', 'Feather', 'Gallatin', 'Jet', 'Upbang', 'Wave', 'Web', 'Knit', 'Number1', 'PL', 'SN9', 'Upbang', 'Kringel', 'Oscar', 'SN4', 'Topless', 'Zap', 'Gallatin', 'Jet', 'Ripplefluke', 'SN90', 'Web', 'Patchback', 'SN96', 'TR77', 'Trigger', 'Scabs', 'Jet', 'Ripplefluke', 'SN90', 'Upbang', 'Web', 'Hook', 'MN83', 'Scabs', 'Shmuddel', 'SN4', 'SN63', 'SN9', 'Stripes', 'TR99', 'TSN103', 'Jonah', 'MN83', 'SN9', 'Topless', 'Vau', 'Zap', 'Kringel', 'Scabs', 'SN4', 'SN63', 'TR99', 'MN23', 'Mus', 'Number1', 'Quasi', 'Web', 'Kringel', 'MN105', 'MN83', 'Patchback', 'Topless', 'Trigger', 'PL', 'Upbang', 'Oscar', 'SN100', 'SN63', 'Thumper', 'TR77', 'TR99', 'Patchback', 'Scabs', 'SN4', 'Topless', 'Trigger', 'SN100', 'Topless', 'Trigger', 'Patchback', 'Topless', 'Trigger', 'Notch', 'Number1', 'Number1', 'PL', 'TR77', 'SMN5', 'Stripes', 'Topless', 'Trigger', 'TSN103', 'SN96', 'TR77', 'Zig', 'Shmuddel', 'SN4', 'SN63', 'SN9', 'Stripes', 'TR99', 'SN4', 'Thumper', 'TR88', 'SN4', 'SN89', 'SN9', 'Zap', 'SN9', 'Stripes', 'Topless', 'Zipfel', 'Stripes', 'Thumper', 'TSN103', 'Whitetip', 'Web', 'TSN103', 'Upbang', 'Web', 'TR77', 'TR99', 'TR120', 'TSN83', 'TR99', 'Trigger', 'Zap', 'TR88', 'Web', 'Trigger', 'Vau', 'Zipfel', 'Web']
dict = {'source': source, 'target': target} 
df_dol = pd.DataFrame(dict)    
print(df_dol) 

# Turn dataframe into graph object
import networkx as nx
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_dol, 'source', 'target', edge_attr=None, create_using=nx.Graph())
nodes = g.nodes()
edges = g.edges()
print(nx.info(g))
density = nx.density(g)
print("Network density:", density)

# Run the community detection algorithm of your choice (e.g. greedy modularity)
from networkx.algorithms import community 
communities = community.greedy_modularity_communities(g)

# Create some empty lists which will later be turned into a dataframe
dens_list=[]
trans_list=[]
top_between_list=[]
member_list=[]
index=0

# Loop through the list of communities
for index,c in enumerate(communities): 
        list(c) 
        index +=1

        # Take slice of dataframe containing only the people in certain community
        # This is done by creating two filters. Then apply these to the original df_dol 
        filter1 = df_dol['source'].isin(c)
        filter2 = df_dol['target'].isin(c)
        name_df = 'df_{}'.format(index)
        name_df = df_dol[filter1 & filter2]
        
        # Create graph object of this community and calculate various metrics
        g = 'G_{}'.format(index)
        g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(name_df, 'source', 'target', edge_attr=None, create_using=nx.Graph())
        
        # Density
        d = 'density_{}'.format(index)
        d = nx.density(g)
        dens_list.append(d)
        
        # Transitivity
        t = 'trans_{}'.format(index)
        t = nx.transitivity(g)
        trans_list.append(t)
        
        # Top betweenness nodes in community
        from operator import itemgetter
        betweenness_dict = nx.betweenness_centrality(g)
        nx.set_node_attributes(g, betweenness_dict, 'betweenness')
        sorted_betweenness = sorted(betweenness_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        top_between = sorted_betweenness[:5]
        top_between_list.append(top_between)
        
        # Finally add all members of a given community
        member_list.append(c)

# Create dictionary of lists        
dict = {'density':dens_list,'transitivity':trans_list,'top_betweenness':top_between_list, 'members':member_list}
# And convert to dataframe which contains the specific characteristics of each community
df_community = pd.DataFrame(dict)

# Clean the two columns with lists
df_community['top_betweenness'] = [','.join(map(str, l)) for l in df_community['top_betweenness']]
df_community['top_betweenness'] = df_community['top_betweenness'].str.replace('(', ' ') 
df_community['top_betweenness'] = df_community['top_betweenness'].str.replace(')', '') 
df_community['members'] = [','.join(map(str, l)) for l in df_community['members']]
df_community['members'] = df_community['members'].str.replace(',', ', ') 

# Print df
print(df_community)
```

The output looks likes this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In R/igraph, you can use the `induced_subgraph()` function to extract a community as a separate graph. You can then run any analysis you like on it.

Example:

```r
g <- make_graph('Zachary')

cl <- cluster_walktrap(g)

# create a subgraph for each community
glist <- lapply(groups(cl), function (p) induced_subgraph(g, p))

# compute your network property of choice for subgraphs
lapply(glist, edge_density)
```

Here's how to do the same with python-igraph:

```py
In [1]: import igraph as ig

In [2]: g = ig.Graph.Famous("Zachary")

In [3]: cl = g.community_walktrap()

In [4]: glist = cl.as_clustering().subgraphs()

In [5]: [g.density() for g in glist]
Out[5]: 
[0.4166666666666667,
 0.2857142857142857,
 0.6,
 0.4166666666666667,
 0.6666666666666666]
```